# Unión de tablas SQL que contienen números de registros distintos

Tags: mysql, sql, datatables, mariadb

Necesito unir las sumas de los `price` en función del `type`

Tabla `tableA`:

| type | priceA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 400 |

Tabla `tableB`:

| type | priceB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 |

Tabla `type`:

| is | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

Lo que intenté:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS type;

CREATE TABLE type
(
     id     varchar(300),
     type   varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO type ( id , type )
VALUES
    ('1', 'A'),
    ('2', 'B');
    
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tableA;
CREATE TABLE tableA
(
     type_id    varchar(300),
     price  varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO tableA ( type_id , priceA )
VALUES
    ('1', '100'),
    ('2', '400');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tableB;
CREATE TABLE tableB
(
     type_id    varchar(300),
     price  varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO tableB ( type_id , priceB )
VALUES
    ('1', '500');
    
SELECT type, COALESCE(SUM(Aprice), 0 ) as sumAprice, COALESCE(SUM(Bprice), 0 ) as sumBprice FROM type
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT type_id, COALESCE (( priceA ), 0 ) AS Aprice FROM tableA GROUP BY type_id ) A ON type.id = A.type_id 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT type_id, COALESCE (( priceB ), 0 ) AS Bprice FROM tableB GROUP BY type_id ) B ON type.id = B.type_id 
GROUP BY type;
```

Se puede ver en: https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle=ca8bddb8f96c76bf990d28bfdeb34de89758bf3dd81c7f1c4827d1b931dafc8e

Obteniendo:

| type | sumAprice | sumBprice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 500 |
| B | 400 | 0 |

Pero no está correcto, necesito que se muestre de la siguiente manera:

| type | sumAprice | sumBprice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 600 | 500 |
| B | 400 | 0 |

Cómo puedo corregir o cambiar la consulta para obtener los datos correctamente?

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer es confuso y no se entiende, considera plantear nuevamente lo que quieres lograr. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo siento que la consulta no esta mal, y que lo que estas pidiendo si haría que el resultado fuera erróneo, creo que lo que debes hacer es crear otra columna donde se sumen los precios, así:

```
SELECT type, COALESCE(SUM(Aprice), 0 ) as sumAprice, COALESCE(SUM(Bprice), 0 ) as sumBprice, (COALESCE(SUM(Aprice), 0 )+COALESCE(SUM(Bprice), 0 )) as total FROM type
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT type_id, COALESCE (price , 0 ) AS Aprice FROM tableA GROUP BY type_id ) A ON type.id = A.type_id 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT type_id, COALESCE (price , 0 ) AS Bprice FROM tableB GROUP BY type_id ) B ON type.id = B.type_id 
GROUP BY type;
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu respuesta y ayuda. Sucede que necesito mostrar la tabla como la que indico correcta. Modifiqué los nombres para que se pueda entender mejor. Gracias!! Cómo se puede lograr?